# How to create an "invalidation request" on Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, online-storage

I am using Amazon S3 with CloudFront. I have some images that I have updated on S3 but the updated versions are not showing up.

It looks like I need to do "invalidation requests" for them but I can't find an easy way to do this. Is this possible via Amazon's own tools? Is there another online service that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this popped up again I will add that CloudFront now allows you to create invalidation requests through Amazon's own interface. Steps:

1. Log into AWS and go to CloudFront.
2. Click the "i" icon next to the appropriate distribution.
3. Go to the "Invalidations" tab and click "Create Invalidation".
4. Enter the files, one per line (paths starting from root) and click "Invalidate".

Answer (score 1):

The Cyberduck app has built-in invalidation request functionality, if a GUI solution is ok.

http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/s3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/) by following these steps : [Create CloudFront Invalidation for any created CloudFront Distribution](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/cloudfront--how-to-create-cloudfront-invalidation.html) .

It works on every Os including Mac, Linux & Windows.